# Как менять id в тэге input при выборе li

Tags: javascript, html

есть ul в котором указаны элементы li допустим:

> - 1
> - 2
> - 3
> - 4

есть input, допустим:
input type="number" id="not"

Как мне менять id="not", допустим на id="one" при выборе

> 1

, менять на id="two" при выборе

> 2

и так далее?

Comment: какая у вас задача? И можно ваш пример для наглядности

Comment: менять id - не очень умно. Правильнее было бы использовать data- атрибут

Answer (score 1):

кмк лучшим выбором будет использовать стандартный подход

> есть input, допустим: input type="number" id="not" Как мне менять id="not", допустим на id="one" при выборе

т.е. инпут вам нужен в качестве хранилища, а LI в качестве контроллера.

```css
.lists > *{display: list-item;}
```

```html
<div class='lists'>
<label for='m1'>1</label>
<label for='m2'>2</label>
<label for='m3'>3</label>
<label for='m4'>4</label>
</div>

<div class='lists'>
<input type='radio' name='my_data' id='m1' value='1'/>
<input type='radio' name='my_data' id='m2' value='2'/>
<input type='radio' name='my_data' id='m3' value='3'/>
<input type='radio' name='my_data' id='m4' value='4'/>
</div>
```

если же надо именно number + ul

```js
function x(my_var)
{document.getElementById('mynum').value=my_var;}
```

```html
<input type='number' id='mynum'/>
<ul>
<li onclick='x(1);'>1</li>
<li onclick='x(2);'>2</li>
<li onclick='x(3);'>3</li>
<li onclick='x(4);'>4</li>
</ul>
```